# first item in cart wont register php mysqli

Tags: php, cookies, mysqli

I have made a website for a university unit with mysqli and php - (beginner) -www.mandyevansartist.com
-where i have a database of different images. When you click on 'gallery' in the menu bar it uses a select statement to display the catagory head . When you click a picture it uses a select statement to display the images in that catagory. When you click on an image it takes you to a full sized display of that image with different options to buy it in a card/small print/big print/poster (each option being a link to a seperate query sending the image to the cart)
The problem is that when a new user sends something to the cart for the first time - the image will not turn up in the cart...every time after that it works perfectly. I suspect it is the cookie or the sessions but cant pinpoint why. 
The relevant code for the images page is

```html
function GetCartId()
{
// This function will generate an encrypted string and
// will set it as a cookie using set_cookie. This will
// also be used as the cookieId field in the cart table
if(isset($_COOKIE["cartId"]))
{
return $_COOKIE["cartId"];
}
else
{
// There is no cookie set. We will set the cookie
// and return the value of the users session ID
session_start();
setcookie("cartId", session_id(), time() + ((3600 * 24) * 30));
return session_id();
}
}


// Get data from the database depending on the value of the id in the URL

 
 $id = $_GET["id"];
 $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE image= '$id'";
 $rs = mysqli_query($con,$strSQL);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {

$name =   $row['image_name'];
echo '<h1 style="font-size:2em;">';
echo $name;
echo'</h1>';
echo '<div id = "galpic">';
$thispic = $row['image'];
echo '<div id = "pic">';  
echo '<br /> <img src="'.$thispic.'" style = "max-width:100%;"/> ';
echo '</div>';  
$description =   $row['image_description'];


echo ' <a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="about" data-animation="fade"><h3>about</h3></a>';
echo ' <a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="card" data-animation="fade"><h3>card</h3></a>';
echo ' <a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="small" data-animation="fade"><h3>small</h3></a>';
echo ' <a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="big" data-animation="fade"><h3>big</h3></a>';
echo ' <a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="triptych" data-animation="fade"><h3>limited</h3></a>';
echo ' <a href="#" class="big-link" data-reveal-id="share" data-animation="fade"><h3>share</h3></a>';
echo '</div>';  


 }

$_SESSION['name'] = $name; 
$_SESSION['thispic'] = $thispic;

echo '<div id="about" class="reveal-modal">';
echo '<br /> <img src="'.$thispic.'" /> ';
echo '<h1>';
echo $description;
echo '</h1>';
echo '</div>';


echo '<div id="card" class="reveal-modal">';
echo '<br /> <img src="'.$thispic.'" /> ';
echo '<img src="images/cards.png" /> ';
echo '<h1>a card of -'.$name.'</h1>';
echo '<p>click this button and we will hand make you this card. Using spray glue on recycled card and a crystal archive photograph. Individually wrapped with a c5 envelope. </p>';
echo '<h1>$7 each</h1><br />';

echo '<form action = "cart.php" method = "post">';
echo '<input type="image" src = "images/sendtocart.png" >';
echo '</form>';
echo '<p> you can remove it from the cart later if you like</p>';
echo '</div>';
```

and the code for 'card.php' (an example of one of the querys that send stuff to the cart)

```html
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;
$_SESSION['thispic'] = $thispic;


$con = mysqli_connect("mandyevansartistcom.ipagemysql.com","x32167022","x32167022","x32167022");
function GetCartId()
{
// This function will generate an encrypted string and
// will set it as a cookie using set_cookie. This will
// also be used as the cookieId field in the cart table
if(isset($_COOKIE["cartId"]))
{
return $_COOKIE["cartId"];
}
else
{
// There is no cookie set. We will set the cookie
// and return the value of the users session ID
session_start();
setcookie("cartId", session_id(), time() + ((3600 * 24) * 30));
return session_id();
}
}



mysqli_query($con,"insert into cart(product,name,image,price,cookieId) values('card','$name','$thispic',7,'".GetCartId()."')");

 header("Location: image.php?id=$thispic");
?>
```

thanks very much for any help

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if it's the solution but i think it's the core of your problem. First of all `session_start();` does't have any effect and is only provoking an error or warning. I'm talking here about the `session_start();` in your `else` statement.

Also, you are talking about "The relevant code for the images page is". Ok, but be sure you are not echo anything else before you call the `setcookie`. You will get a `Cannot modify header information` warning and the cookie **won't** be set. E.g.

```
echo "blabla";
setcookie("cartId", session_id(), time() + ((3600 * 24) * 30));
//Cookie isn't set!
```

Correct:

```
setcookie("cartId", session_id(), time() + ((3600 * 24) * 30));
//Cookie is set correctly!
```